# Use i in variable name

Tags: c#

So I have this kind of code (I'm assigning values to XAML elements
), which begs for a "for" loop.

```
Day1d.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
Day2d.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(2));
Day3d.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(3));
Day4d.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(4));

Day1t.Text = "°" + (myWeatherForecast.forecastlist[1].temp).ToString();
Day2t.Text = "°" + (myWeatherForecast.forecastlist[2].temp).ToString();
Day3t.Text = "°" + (myWeatherForecast.forecastlist[3].temp).ToString();
Day4t.Text = "°" + (myWeatherForecast.forecastlist[4].temp).ToString();
```

But all my attempts to include "i" in variable name failed miserably. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: make an array of Day.d objects, then use `i` as the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a loop where you iterate over the instances:

```
int counter = 1; // are you sure it shouldn't start at 0?
foreach (TextBox tb in new TextBox[] { Day1d, Day2d, Day3d, Day4d })
{
    tb.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(counter));

    counter++;
}

counter = 1;
foreach (TextBox tb in new TextBox[] { Day1t, Day2t, Day3t, Day4t })
{
    tb.Text = "°" + (myWeatherForecast.forecastlist[counter].temp).ToString();

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it starts at 1, because day0 is a special instance, I populate it with a little bit different information (as you may have figured this is a weather app, and weather for today is much more important).

Comment: Okay. That sounds logical.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compose the name of the variable using another variable. The way to do this would be to create a List and then iterate over that List

```
var textBoxes1 = new List<TextBox> { Day1d, Day2d, Day3d, Day4d }
var textBoxes2 = new List<TextBox> { Day1t, Day2t, Day3t, Day4t }
foreach (var textbox in textBoxes1)
{
    var index = textBoxes1.IndexOf(textBox) + 1;
    textbox.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(index));
}
foreach (var textbox in textBoxes2)
{
    var index = textBoxes2.IndexOf(textBox) + 1;
    textbox.Text = "°" + (myWeatherForecast.forecastlist[index].temp).ToString();
}
```

NOTE: You can solve this in different ways:

- using arrays instead of lists
- keeping your own counter, instead of doing IndexOf
- using a for loop, instead of a foreach

Which one is better is mostly based on opinion (although my method is not the fastest, but it doesn't matter if you only have 4 items)

Comment: Why use `IndexOf` if you can calculate the index much more efficient?

Comment: Cause it doesn't really matter, you're iterating over 4 items and I think it looks cleaner.

Comment: Personally I disagree.

Comment: All primarly opinion based. Truth is, for this example it doesn't matter, the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FindName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) assuming you are using WPF.

Try:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
     ((TextBox)this.FindName("Day" + i + "d")).Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(i));
     ((TextBox)this.FindName("Day" + i + "t")).Text = "°" + (myWeatherForecast.forecastlist[i].temp).ToString();
}
```