# Is there an easier way to do a list of variables in c# Buttons, Checkboxes, Labels

Tags: c#

Currently my program works flawlessly, my only complaint is it has these giant switch statements with 5 lines of code, in one line. It looks tacky, and it's hard to read. But I don't want 50 lines of code to scroll through for my switch statement.

I was wondering, if I labeled my buttons, check-boxes or labels if I could do something like an array to be the current number; like checkbox1, checkbox2 would be checkbox[1] and checkbox[2]. Doing that now, does not work, so I'm looking for a workaround to this. I would really like to use a for loop if possible, because writing out the same thing 10 times is very tedius and much more time consuming then I would like it to be.

Below is what my switch statement looks like.

```
switch (currentProblem){
    case 1: problem1.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); break;
    case 2: problem2.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem2.Visible = true; c2.Visible = true; answer2.Visible = true; break;
    case 3: problem3.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem3.Visible = true; c3.Visible = true; answer3.Visible = true; break;
    case 4: problem4.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem4.Visible = true; c4.Visible = true; answer4.Visible = true; break;
    case 5: problem5.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem5.Visible = true; c5.Visible = true; answer5.Visible = true; break;
    case 6: problem6.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem6.Visible = true; c6.Visible = true; answer6.Visible = true; break;
    case 7: problem7.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem7.Visible = true; c7.Visible = true; answer7.Visible = true; break;
    case 8: problem8.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem8.Visible = true; c8.Visible = true; answer8.Visible = true; break;
    case 9: problem9.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem9.Visible = true; c9.Visible = true; answer9.Visible = true; break;
    case 10: problem10.Text = (num1 + sign + num2).ToString(); problem10.Visible = true; c10.Visible = true; answer10.Visible = true; break;
}
switch (hiddenCurrentLabel.Text)
{
    case "1": if (answer1.Text != "") { if (answer1.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c1.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); return;
    case "2": if (answer2.Text != "") { if (answer2.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c2.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); return;
    case "3": if (answer3.Text != "") { if (answer3.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c3.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); break;
    case "4": if (answer4.Text != "") { if (answer4.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c4.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); break;
    case "5": if (answer5.Text != "") { if (answer5.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c5.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); break;
    case "6": if (answer6.Text != "") { if (answer6.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c6.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); break;
    case "7": if (answer7.Text != "") { if (answer7.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c7.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); break;
    case "8": if (answer8.Text != "") { if (answer8.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c8.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); break;
    case "9": if (answer9.Text != "") { if (answer9.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c9.Checked = true; } addOne(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); break;
    case "10": if (answer10.Text != "") { if (answer10.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text) { c10.Checked = true; } getAverage(); } else { break; } t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); break;
}
```

The second one is where having it in a for loop would have saved a LOT of time.

Comment: [Related or duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36045587/993547).

Comment: Thanks patrick, I'll have to try that. not exactly what I was thinking of, but if it works, it works. ;)

Comment: The solution is the same: iterate over an array and do something with that. An `if` statement might do in your case.

Comment: Use arrays or lists of controls. That way you could access controls like this : `TextBoxes[i]=..`

Comment: Now my only concern is, if I run this for loop, will it halt the program until it's done AKA if I'm waiting on answers, will it make the answers unable to be input, because it's unable to leave the for loop? Or would I be better of setting it up as a do while loop, so I can cancel out whenever I need to?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ActivateCurrentProblem(int i){
          Textbox problem =  Controls.Find("problem" + i, true);
          Textbox answer =  Controls.Find("answer" + i, true);
          CheckBox c =  Controls.Find("c" + i, true);
          problem.Text =(num1 + sign + num2).ToString();
          problem.Visible=true;
          answer.Visible=true;
         if (answer.Text == hiddenAnswerLabel.Text)
         { 
             c.Checked = true; 
             addOne();
         }
         t = int.Parse(hiddenCurrentLabel.Text); chooseRandoms(t); 
     }
```

And the usage:

```
ActivateCurrentProblem(3);
```

Or you can just use an Array:

```
Textbox[] txt = new Textbox[10]; 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     txt[i] = new Textbox(){
        Location =new Point(0, i*40),  //values are just examples
        Visible= true,
        ....
    };
    Controls.Add(txt[i]);
}
```

Comment: A nice solution. - Note that for this to work the controls must have their `Name` property set. The designer will do that by default, but if they are created dynamically it is the responsibilty of the coder to set it to the expected value..!

Comment: ... which is why I prefer an array over this.

Comment: If I'm reading this properly, it's comparing the variable name of my textboxes to "problem"+i. Where if i was 1 it would see the problem as problem1 or is my understanding flawed? If thats the case, it could be a shorter but more convoluted (to me) way of making a makeshift array. Would make it so I don't have to type out `{ problem1, problem2, problem3, problem4, problem5, problem6, problem7, problem8, problem9, problem10 };` to create the variable names

Comment: @PatrickHofman I prefer array too. but the question indicates that the user has not used an array.

Comment: So, why can't he use it then?

Comment: I didn't know how to use an array for this situation, which is why I asked :)

Comment: _if I'm reading this properly, it's comparing the variable name of my textboxes to "problem"+i._ __Wrong!__ It is __not__ comparing the __variable names__ but the `Name` __property__ ! (Which is not really safe to identify a control as it needs neither be set at all nor be unique..). But if they are set correctly, it will work fine.

Comment: Both of the ways you gave answers to me, are giving me a difficult time understanding them. Mostly because a constantly running program that waits for user input for each question, then opens the next question, in my head, would halt on the first question. I don't think it actually would, but it could raise problems as the program runs.

Comment: well I don't see your program. just create the array with visible = false. and set same `Location` (left and top) for all of them then you can use a function that shows the question you want like: `public void ShowQuestion(int index){for(int i=0;i<10;i++) if(i==index)txt[i].Visible=true; else txt[i].Visible=false; } `

Comment: If you need help over this, then lets go to chat.

Comment: This mini video (mute it, avoid static noise) shows what the program does when its launched, and that its in seperate functions of the program that updates when clicked, or when something updates. It doesn't happen all at the same time. https://youtu.be/6tAbTGJWB1I

Comment: All loops suggested do the same as your original code:They process exactly one set of control! The loops simply search for the right set of controls..